# ORACLE bulk insert based on SQL

Tags: c++, oracle, bulkinsert

Ich have to shuffle a lot of data data from an application into an ORACLE 11g database. To execute SQL from within C++ I use to employ the following scheme, using bare SQL together with the Poco::Data framework and an ODBC connection to my database:

```
    // get session  from ODBC session pool 
    Session session = moc::SessionPoolMOC::get();

    // prepare a statement as QString
    QString q = ("INSERT INTO MOC_DATA_CONCENTRATOR"
        "("
        "EQUIPMENT_INSTANCE_ID, "
        "STATION_NAME, "
        "DATA_SRC, "
        "ORG_ID)"
        "values (%1, '%2', '%3', %4);"
        );

    /*
    there would be also prepared statements, but I think that is not the 
    topic now...
    */


    // set parameters within string from passed object 'info'
    q = q.arg(info.equipment_instance_id);              /* 1 */
    q = q.arg(info.station_name.toUtf8().constData());  /* 2 */
    q = q.arg(info.data_src.toUtf8().constData());      /* 3 */
    q = q.arg(info.org_id);                             /* 4 */

    // prepare statement
    Statement query(session);
    query << q.toUtf8().constData();
    try
    {
        // execute query
        query.execute();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
       ...
    }
```

I'm aware, that this is a very low level approach, but it worked really fine for all situations I encountered so far...

The problem is, that I have now a lot of data (about 400,000 records) to fill into one table. Data is available as different C++ objects, stored in a Qt-List. My naive approach is to call this code sequence for each object to insert. This works fine, but turns out to be quite slow (taking about 15 minutes or so). I asked around, and was told to better use a so called "bulk insert".

It seems, however, that this is more related to PLSQL - at least I have no Idea how to use that from the same context or in a similar way as shown in my example. I'm neither ORACLE expert nor administrator and usage of the database is only a side problem within my project. What would you recommend?

Many thanks,
Michael

Comment: Can you store the data in a PL/SQL collection? Can you make a new PL/SQL procedure in the database? If so, you should store the data in a collection and pass it to the procedure which would bulk insert all the objects in the collection

Comment: I could make a new procedure - yes. But how do I pass values to it by the scheme above?

Comment: I could help you with the PL/SQL part but I don't know how values are passed in C++